# Layover in Incheon, do I need a transit visa?

Tags: transit-visas, south-korea, filipino-citizens

We are a Philippine Passport holder. We already have a Japan Visa. We already have a Ticket for our return flight. Unfortunately, it is connecting with Korea. May I know if do we need to secure a transit/travel Visa if we'll going to use Incheon as our connecting flight to Clark, Philippines?

The flight details. Narita to Incheon (11:30AM-2:35PM) and Incheon to Clark (9:35PM-12:05AM)

Answer (score 1):

You need a C-3 visa:

> Philippine citizens traveling to South Korea need passports with remaining validity of at least 90 days following their departure date from South Korea. Filipino travelers may apply for the short-term or C-3 visa, which is given for the purpose of tourism, transit, visiting relative, conference and religious ceremony.

([Source](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwiX56yNkKXkAhVDtHEKHa65CFUQFjABegQICxAF&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftouringbuddy.com%2Fvisa-requirements-philippine-passport-holders-%25E2%2580%2593-south-korea-republic-korea%2F&usg=AOvVaw1pWj_QrdCFhjIQJwPQjQzu))